# What is wrong with my elif statement? Invalid Syntax

Tags: python-3.3

```
if option == "1":
    with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
        print(f.read())

    numbers = []

    with open("sample2.txt","r") as f:
        for i in range(9):
            numbers.append(f.readline().strip())
        print(numbers)

        from random import randint

    for i in range(9):
        print(numbers[randint(0,8)])

from tkinter import *

def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    mLabel2 = Label(test, text=mtext).pack()
    return

test = Tk()
ment = StringVar()
test.geometry('450x450+500+10')
test.title('Test')
mlabel = Label(test, text='Time to guess').pack()         
mbutton = Button(test, text='Click', command = mhello).pack()         
mEntry = Entry(test, textvariable=ment).pack()
test.mainloop()

from tkinter import *
def mhello():
    my_word = 'HELLO'
    mtext = ment.get()
    if my_word == mtext:
        mLabel2 = Label(test, text='Correct').pack()

    else:
        mLabel2 = Label(test, text='Incorrect').pack()
    return
test = Tk()
ment = StringVar()
test.geometry('450x450+500+300')
test.title('Test')
def label_1():
label_1 = Label(test, text='Hello. Welcome to my game.').pack()
def label_2():
    label_2 = Label(test, text='What word am I thinking of?').pack()
    button_1 = Button(test, text='Click', command = mhello).pack()
    entry_1 = Entry(test, textvariable=ment).pack()
label_1()
test.after(5000, label_2)
test.mainloop()
from tkinter import *
from random import shuffle
game = Tk()
game.geometry('200x200')
game.grid()
game.title("My Game")
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
def board_1():
    board1 = []
    k = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            board1.append(Label(game, text = board[k]))
            board1[k].grid(row = i, column = j)
            k +=1
def board_2():
    shuffle(board)
    board2 = []
    k = 0
        for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            board2.append(Label(game, text = board[k]))
            board2[k].grid(row = i, column = j)
            k +=1
board_1()
game.after(5000, board_2)
game.mainloop()

#2nd Option
    elif option == "2":
        print ("You have chosen option 2. Well Done, You Can Type! XD")
```

The bit that has the Syntax Error is the 1st elif statement (2nd Option). Ignore all the code prior to this if necessary (it is there for context). Whenever I run the code it says that there is a syntax error and just positions the typing line (I don't know what it's called) at the end of the word elif.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix, with if else statements you need to have a closing ELSE and in this case there is not so when your program runs it sees that theres a lonely if without its else :)

```
if option == "1":

elif option == "2":

else:
    'do something else in the program if any other value was recieved'
```

also a switch statement can be used here so it does not keep checking each condition and just goes straight to the correct case :D

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I do already have an else statement in my actual code, I just could not put it in as there was already too much code in the question

Comment: Not a problem! did you refer to andreas-hofmann answer? what is the update on this question have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your block is separated from the first if-statement, where it actually belongs to. As it is, it follows the `game.mainloop()` statement, and adds an unexpected indentation. Try to rearrange your code like so:

```
if option == "1":
    with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
        print(f.read())

    numbers = []

    with open("sample2.txt","r") as f:
        for i in range(9):
            numbers.append(f.readline().strip())
        print(numbers)

        from random import randint

    for i in range(9):
        print(numbers[randint(0,8)])
elif option == "2":
    print ("You have chosen option 2. Well Done, You Can Type! XD")

[ Rest of the code ]
```